# What is the difference between bundle pack and bundle cache

Tags: ruby, bundler

I cannot see the `bundle pack` command in the latest version of the bundler documentation, but it is still in the older version. There is no mention about it being deprecated either (AFAIK). The documentation content looks similar to `bundle cache`. Is it safe to assume that they are the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bundle pack` is (or was) an alias of the `bundle package` command.

`bundle cache` and `bundle package` used to be separate commands. With Bundler 2.4.0, the previous `package` subcommand was integrated into the cache subcommand with pull requests [#7724](https://github.com/rubygems/bundler/pull/7249) and [#7389](https://github.com/rubygems/bundler/pull/7389).

All three commands (`cache`, `package` and `pack`) now do the exact same thing and are simple aliases. Preferably, you should use `bundle cache` as the primary name of the subcommand.